# Повесить событие на коллекцию

Tags: события, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста решить проблему.

На [страничке](http://jsfiddle.net/YABB9/) хотелось бы повесить событие по клику на те `article` , которые находятся в блоке `#container`

Допустим, `article` может быть намного больше чем сейчас. Например 200

Желательно обойтись без циклов и использовать чистый `javascript`

Comment: Вы слышали про jQuery ? Не стоит писать велосипеды. Воспользуйтесь готовой функцией [jQuery:on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: я слышал про jquery и даже писал на нём несколько лет. теперь захотелось копнуть поглубже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно повесить на `container` событие `mouseup`, оно срабатывает и для дочерних элементов. А затем уже по этому событию проверять `target` события:

```
function addEvent(element, eventType, handler){
    if(element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventType, handler);
    else
        element.attachEvent(eventType, handler);
}

var c = document.getElementById('container');
addEvent(c, 'mouseup', function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'article')
    {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/YABB9/1/

**UPDATE:** Судя по всему можно и напрямую вешать `click`: http://jsfiddle.net/YABB9/3/

Comment: большое спасибо

а не подскажете как сделать только выборку по article , которые в #container. то есть просто получить коллекцию элементов

вот такой способ не работает
var a = getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('article');

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin: исправьте на var a = *document*.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('article');

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('article');

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
a[i].addEventListener( "click" , function(e){
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: всем спасибо

Comment: Лучше использовать делегирование(описал @Павел Азанов) если элементов  в колекции много то сильно скажется на производительности